# Angularjs: data not produced from ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the example below, I get the first table of data **(1)**. From the table produced I want to unhide an adjacent table and populate it with data from another JSON source when the line is clicked.

The table account value gets sent to the 'go' function, the table is shown but is not populated with data.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**//angularjs to fetch JSON data for table **(1)****

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://Amanda/test2.aspx")
.then((response) =>{
$scope.recds = response.data.records;

});
```

**//angularjs to fetch JSON data for charges**

```
$scope.go=function(x) {
 


    **//charges service**
        app.service('dataService',getJsonData = function($scope, $http) 
        {           
            return $http.get('http://Amanda/Charges.aspx?ac=' + x).then((response) =>{ 
            return response.data.records2;            
            });                
        });


    **// charges controller**
        app.controller('customersCtrl2', function($scope, $http,dataService) {
        $scope.recds2 = dataService.getJsonData(x);
        
        });
    
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = 'visible';
            
        };


            
});
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #F1FAFA">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table id="Summary">
<tr>
<th class="auto-style6" style="width: 66px">Annual<br>Ranking<br><span class="auto-style7">(this week)</span></th>
<th>Account</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>Cust <br> Status</th>
<th>% of <br>Annual<br>Revenue</th>
<th>This week</th>
<th>week-1</th>
<th style="width: 71px">week-2</th>
<th>week-3</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp; YTD <br>Revenue</th>
<th>Receipted<br>Loads</th>
<th>Receipted <br>Pallets</th>
<th>Delivery <br>Loads</th>
<th>Delivery<br>Pallets</th>
<th>Last<br>Agreed £</th>


</tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in recds" ng-click="go(x.Account);" >
    <td class="auto-style2" style="width: 66px">{{ x.Position }}<span class="auto-style8"> ({{ x.WPosition }})</span></td>
    <td id="act" class="auto-style2">{{ x.Account }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style2" >{{ x.Customer }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style2">{{ x.CType }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.Perc }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style5"><span class="auto-style4">{{ x.ThisWeek}}&nbsp;</span><img ng-src="{{(x.LastWeek - x.ThisWeek) < 0 && 'Images/green.png' || 'Images/red.png'}}" class="auto-style4" style="float: right"></td>
    <td class="auto-style1"><span class="auto-style4">{{ x.LastWeek }}&nbsp;</span><img ng-src="{{(x.Week2 - x.LastWeek) < 0 && 'Images/green.png' || 'Images/red.png'}}" class="auto-style4" style="float: right"></td>
    <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 71px"><span class="auto-style4">{{ x.Week2 }}&nbsp;</span><img ng-src="{{(x.Week3 - x.Week2) < 0 && 'Images/green.png' || 'Images/red.png'}}" class="auto-style4" style="float: right"></td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.Week3 }}</td>    
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.YTD }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.recs }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.recsplt }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.dels }}</td>
    <td class="auto-style3">{{ x.delsplt }}</td>
    <td id="preview" class="auto-style3">{{ x.preview }}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>


 <div id="div1" class="block2" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl2">
  <table id="charge">
  <tr>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Chargecode</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
</tr>

<----- data below not produced----->

  <tr ng-repeat="y in recds2">
    <td>{{ y.Customer }}</td>
    <td>{{ y.ChargeCode }}</td>
    <td>{{ y.Charge }}</td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can anybody held here please?

Comment: No Takers? A data table is produced ok but I want to click on a line and display another  table of charges relating to the selection. The line is selected and passed to 'go' function OK but the charge table is not populated and I am stumped as to why not.